# How to generate update SQL statements after updating the records in the database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I am using MSAccess to connect to a SQL Server and update records. I need to later apply these changes to another server. Is there an easy way that can generate the update statements for me so that I can run the script on another database without have to copy over the entire table? I have Access and SMSS tools that I am currently using.

Comment: Please give more details how do you update the data. If thru forms, there is no easy way for capturing SQL with binding parameters values. You may want to look at SQL Server replication feature.

Comment: Just through raw Access tables that looks like an spreadsheet. I don't need to capture the updates as they happen. If I can just generate update queries after the fact would work as well.